# Set scroll to section with offset in elementor?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

Any quick way of setting offset for setting scroll to a section in wordpress elementor plugin?

After a user clicks on each of the four sections below the first section, the page must scroll to the booking section. But it almost stops after the section.

https://smart-click.agency/web-design-and-development/

Short Elementor or CSS solution preferable over JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet rather than linking to your website.

Comment: thanks for you attention zack. as i mentioned the website is design over elementor page builder and just a few lines of CSS is used for some styles. so i dont understand what do you mean by providing a code snippets as its all done via a page builder

Answer (score 0):

you can use Menu Anchor widget in Elementor. There is no build-in offset setting to do that. But you can use simple CSS code:

```
#sectionID {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: -180px;
```

}

To get sectionID you should define it in the advance tab of the section that you want to scroll. There is a field called: CSS ID.